ArrayInput + SimpleFormIterator no working correctly inside the TranslatableInputs component in React Admin 5.1
I have a form in my project, that is a combination of ArrayInput + SimpleFormIterator inside TranslatableInputs component.
const OrderEdit = () => (
  <Edit>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextInput source="customer"/>
      <TranslatableInputs locales={['en', 'fr']}>
        <ArrayInput source="items">
          <SimpleFormIterator>
            <TextInput source="name"/>
          </SimpleFormIterator>
        </ArrayInput>
      </TranslatableInputs>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);

In React Admin 4.x it works correctly, however in 5.1 it does not load the actual values ​​of the items and the Delete button does not remove value of the items prop.
SimpleFormIterator.gif

I need the component show current data of items field.
i need the component remove data of items if press remove button.


Related GH Issue (with an alternative solution): https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/10130

Using TranslatableContextProvider, TranslatableInputsTabContent and useTranslatable hook you can achieve it.
Update your code as follow:
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput,
  ArrayInput,
  SimpleFormIterator,
  TranslatableInputsTabContent,
  TranslatableContextProvider,
  useTranslatable,
  TranslatableInputsTabs,
} from "react-admin";

export const OrderEdit = () => {
  const context = useTranslatable({ locales: ["en", "fr"] });

  return (
    <Edit>
      <TranslatableContextProvider value={context}>
        <TranslatableInputsTabContent locale={context.selectedLocale}>
          <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="customer" />
            <TranslatableInputsTabs />
            <ArrayInput source="items">
              <SimpleFormIterator>
                <TextInput source="name" />
              </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
          </SimpleForm>
        </TranslatableInputsTabContent>
      </TranslatableContextProvider>
    </Edit>
  );
};

